# Why do medical institutes block VPNs?

Tags: vpn

I was faced with a security control i never saw before,
recent i was in a local hospital and i tried to connect to a VPN server via NordVPN mobile app. The effect? A graphical infinite loop showed up and it took unexpected long while it never successfully connected to all of their servers. I'm sure it was not a network issue.

Is this of to manage legal security issues?

Comment: This is not really a question. You cite one example that some software did not work, and from that you infer that a.) the facilty has blocked it on purpose, and b.) that medical facilities *in general* block VPN traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that they explicitly block VPN. But it is not uncommon that free networks and sometimes even paid networks in hotels restrict access to only allow web (HTTP/HTTPS) and mail in order to reduce possible misuse of their networks. This can have the side effect of implicitly blocking less common services like VPN as collateral damage.

Specifically for NordVPN see [the NordVPN FAQ for firewall settings](https://nordvpn.com/faq/):

> What ports should be open on firewall/router for it to work?
>   1723, 443 TCP and 1194 UDP ports should be open; also your firewall/router/ISP must allow pass-through for PPTP/VPN.

Likely the firewall in the medical institute does not allow port 1723 and 1194 at all and port 443 for UDP since these are not needed for the usual web and mail traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you provided enough information to assign blame to an anti-VPN “security” measure yet.

Many things may have gone wrong when attempting to establish the VPN connection. They could have had a captive portal interfering with the connection. They could have had any number of network interference problems going on (a DOS attack, ransomware, etc.). And, if we’re being honest, guest WiFi is the lowest priority problem for any network engineer to fix. Keeping the life-critical devices on the network is their highest priority, followed by normal business traffic, network maintenance tasks, firewall configuration requests, incident response, etc. Guest WiFi problems are going to get fixed last.

Next time you’re going to use their WiFi, bring a device with tcpdump or wireshark installed and grab a packet capture. If you see every SYN packet to NordVPN immediately responded to with a RST packet, then you can assume they are deliberately shutting you down. But until you prove hostile intent is the cause, I’d look for other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know how their service works, so I ask: Does taht VPN even go by TCP (so that SYN and RST make sense in the first place)?

Comment: I suppose there’s a very small chance that NordVPN could be using UDP instead of TCP, but I think their users would run into firewall issues everywhere. Some home routers don’t have UDP port forwarding enabled by default, and I wouldn’t bet on random businesses’ guest WiFi networks having UDP port forwarding universally enabled, either.